# Why my segmentation using HSV space isn't giving me a good result?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I am attending a class on image processing with Matlab and I found a problem on the internet and I tried to solve it but it is hard, because I am new to this subject.

The problem has to be solved with Matlab and it is new for me as well.

Problem:

> 'Think of RGB and HSV spaces as 3-dimensional spaces. Define a
> neighborhood distance (we can use ecludien distance) and set to 0 all
> the pixels whose value in RGB or HSV space is far (in the sense of
> this distance) from your reference value. See if you can easily
> achieve the same type of segmentation in both cases. Try for example
> to segment only the helmets of the warriors of the image
> bilibinWar.jpg.'

[image]

I tried to code it but i don't know if the result is good.

```
%%
% 4) 8 - Segmentatiion dans l’’espace HSV et RVB..
clear all; close all;
ImagebilibinWar = imread("bilibinWar.jpg");
[lin, col, pla] = size(ImagebilibinWar);
figure(1);imshow(ImagebilibinWar);
Image_bilibinWar_HSV= rgb2hsv(ImagebilibinWar);
[lo,co] = ginput(1);
lo = round(lo);
co = round(co);
RIOH = Image_bilibinWar_HSV(lo,co,1);


%%
% Im going to use this first  section so ican isolate the helmets inside a circle ARROUND THE HELMETS and get rid of REST background Circle_Image_bilibinWar_HSV = Image_bilibinWar_HSV;
for i= 1:lin
    for j = 1:col
        d(i,j) = ((i-lo)^2 + (j-co)^2)^0.5;
        if d(i,j,:) > 90
            Circle_Image_bilibinWar_HSV(i,j,:) = 0;
        end
    end
end
Circle_Image_bilibinWar_RGB = hsv2rgb(Circle_Image_bilibinWar_HSV);
figure(2);imshow(Circle_Image_bilibinWar_RGB); % i have isolated the circle

%% here im going to isolate the helmets inside the circle 
figure(3); imshow(Circle_Image_bilibinWar_HSV); % as u can see here i will try to isolate the helmets from the rest
New_Circle_Image_bilibinWar_HSV = Circle_Image_bilibinWar_HSV % assinging a new image so as i can work on it seperatly;
valueH = New_Circle_Image_bilibinWar_HSV(lo,co,1);

for i=1:lin
    for j=1:col
        if (New_Circle_Image_bilibinWar_HSV(i,j,1) > valueH + 0.19)
            New_Circle_Image_bilibinWar_HSV(i,j,:) = 0;
        end
    end
end

Circle_Image_bilibinWar_HSV = Circle_Image_bilibinWar_HSV - New_Circle_Image_bilibinWar_HSV;
NEW_Image_bilibinWar_RGB = hsv2rgb(Circle_Image_bilibinWar_HSV);
figure(4); subplot(1,2,1);imshow(ImagebilibinWar);
subplot(1,2,2);imshow(NEW_Image_bilibinWar_RGB);
```

So can some one help me with it? i don't know if its good and if not how can i make it good ?

Comment: Can you explain to us the logic of your code? What is `d`? why that equation?

Comment: hey thanks for ur response,

Comment: well im new to this , and from what ive understood . its like caluculating the diffrence in space between a reference point (i got the H, S & V of this point) and calculated the diffrence between each pixel of my image and this point in term of H,S & V using 3D euclidean distance and then i just choose a reference distance and then i compared the distance that i calculated with reference distance and set everything to 0 if the condition is true. but it doesnt work good, it does a bit of elimination and segmentation  and i did a for loop for reference distance to find the appropriate one

Comment: since they didn't give us one. i dont know if my code is cood or right , its like my second code. i hope u point where i made mistakes or should i change the way ?

Comment: Right, I see. You compute the euclidean distance between a selected pixel and the rest of the world and check for closest. Do you need to do that, or was it your choice? The entire point of HSV space is that only 1 of the 3 values (Hue) represents color, and therefore you can generally "color segment" by just selecting the pixels with the same Hue. In fact, for Euclidean distance segmentation, the `L*a*b` color space is used.

Comment: thank u so much i think i understand more now. i will try to do it .

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything wrong with your code. The answer is that segmenting using euclidean distance in colors simply does not work for RGB or HSV spaces. The entire purpose of the `L*a*b` color space was indeed this, creating a color space where similar colors would have the little euclidean distance.

Here a less cluttered version of it:

```
clear all; close all;
ImagebilibinWar = imread("https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnBDu.jpg");
[lin, col, pla] = size(ImagebilibinWar);
figure;imshow(ImagebilibinWar);
ImagebilibinWarHSV= rgb2hsv(ImagebilibinWar);
[lo,co] = ginput(1);
lo = round(lo);
co = round(co);
RIOH = ImagebilibinWarHSV(lo,co,1);
RIOS = ImagebilibinWarHSV(lo,co,2);
RIOV = ImagebilibinWarHSV(lo,co,3);
%reference value that i have to choose
for a=0:0.05:1

    d = ((ImagebilibinWarHSV(:,:,1)-RIOH).^2 + (ImagebilibinWarHSV(:,:,2)-RIOS).^2+(ImagebilibinWarHSV(:,:,3)-RIOV).^2).^0.5;

    ImagebilibinWarRGB = hsv2rgb(ImagebilibinWarHSV.*double(d<a));
    figure;imshow(ImagebilibinWarRGB);
end
```

Comment: Ah ok i get it now . now just when i asked a teacher he said u can use euclidean distance . and he didnt add anything. but after ur comment i think i know why he said that . when i printed out HSV image i noticed that the helmets and many part of the image have the same color so maybe i should do the euclidean distance so i can in the first time isolate just the helmets and some of their surroundings (like a circle) and do the code above so as it detects only helmts and segment it inside the circle (using the hue) and then i can erase eveything outside the circle as well . i will try it.

Comment: i tried what i said, can u check it for me ?

Comment: @Amine please dont keep updating the question, ask a new one if its needed

Comment: i thought i should continue here, my bad didnt know